# Convert Parse string to integer in Xcode for sorting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have 2 string objects in parse, TeamName and Score, that I am querying, but I would like to treat Score as an integer when queried so I can sort it. I am using Xcode and objective c.  Can someone help me convert the string Score to an integer in Xcode?  Or if I redefine Score as a number how could I convert the code below to display the number Score?  Anything I have tried so far has not worked.

Any help would be appreciated!  I will continue to keep trying things on my end.

My current working code is below, but I am not able to sort the Score strings:

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

return query;

}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object 
  {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
UILabel *team = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *goals = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
team.text = object[@"TeamName”];

goals.text = object[@"Score"];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is get the string - in your case is it goals? Let say you have an int called howMany :

```
howMany = [goals intValue];
```

It is as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I tried that initially and I was always getting the following: No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'intValue'.  When I tried int howMany = [goals.text intValue]; it works and I get a value of 0.  I think because I have a string 'High Score: ' at the beginning it returns 0.  For ex. I will try to pull out just the 60 from 'High Score: 60' by removing the know text.  Let me know if I am missing anything else, thanks!

Comment: The following worked once I removed the known string at the beginning:test1 = [goals.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"High Score: "
                                         withString:@""];
    int test = [test1 intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i",test);